# Set a payload for an aws lambda invoked for password rotation

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

On AWS secret creation I want to configure the secret to use a lambda function to rotate password, and pass the parameters for the rotation. In C# is

```
var response = client.RotateSecret(new RotateSecretRequest  {
RotationLambdaARN = "arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:123456789012:function:MyTestDatabaseRotationLambda",
RotationRules = new RotationRulesType { AutomaticallyAfterDays = 30 },
SecretId = "MyTestDatabaseSecret"  });
```

How do I pass a payload/parameter to MyTestDatabaseRotationLambda? This is to use the same rotation function for all secret managers.

Comment: Doesn't the documentation says "No, you can't?" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets-lambda-function-overview.html 
Secrets Manager invokes the Lambda function with the following JSON request structure of parameters:

{
  "Step" : "request.type",
  "SecretId" : "string",
  "ClientRequestToken" : "string"
}

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that part of the documentation, I overlooked it, I assumed lambda was more flexible in that regards. So knowing that, on what cases would someone create a secret manager and configure a lambda for rotation? Such lambda have to be hardcoded with the DB and secret to rotate/update, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, AWS is not something I am specialized in. I am not able to give you a good answer so I prefer not to, and maybe you should ask this as another question? (Or check if someone had already gone through the same path?)